# Show ComboBox as text and store it as integer in database

Tags: mysql, vb.net

So I have this problem. I have a ComboBox which has a list of courses. The user can choose a list of courses but I want that list of course to be stored in integer and text. The integer will become the id and the text will become the course_name.

Example: 
The user will choose BSIT in comboBox and this will be stored in database

```
id      course_name
1       BSIT
```

I want id and course_name will be stored when a user chooses in comboBox. How to do this?

Comment: not really because what i want is to store both text and the interger

Comment: You didnt give any details as to where the data comes from?  A DB Table (the ID makes that seem likely)?  A DataSource allows exactly that: show one thing and save another